# What this motorcycle engine plug tell about the operation inside engine?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, sparkplugs

[image: spark plug of motorcycle][image]

What does this plug tell about the inside operation of the engine? I can't find any plug that looks like this in any online charts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Color Should the Spark Be When Using a Spark Tester?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27366/what-color-should-the-spark-be-when-using-a-spark-tester)

Comment: You may also find this interesting : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25763/what-is-spark-plug-heat-range?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It would be very helpful to know more about the engine and the application it is being used in. With that information, we stand a better chance of actually answering your question.

Comment: It is 102 cc commuter motorcycle made by Bajaj auto . it uses Dtsi twin spark technology.

Comment: Two stroke engine? How old is that plug? What problem are you having?

Comment: Four stroke engine. 1 year old motorcycle. It has knocking noise at idle. Engine races(idle speed increases)  after riding of about 3-4 kms.

Answer (score 1):

Next time make a picture before you cleaned and sanded the plug, the color of the electrode can tell a lot about operating conditions.

To answer your question: it looks a bit fouled with oily deposits, so its possible the engine is running too rich.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of bike is this plug out of?  Is it carbureted or fuel injected?  As far as your fuel to air ratio, you can install new plugs and do a [plug chop](http://www.braigasen.com/howtoread.htm)